# MarkLogic Java API PlanBuilderBase.ExportablePlanBase

Tags: java, marklogic

I use `PlanBuilder.ModifyPlan` to retrieve the contents and the results are in `StringHandle()`. 
I see the `PlanBuilderBase.ExportablePlanBase` but there is no reference as how to use its `exportAs` method.
This method should be sth like:
`ExportablePlan ep = plan.exportAs(String);`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an application wouldn't call exportAs().

Instead, an application would pass the plan to methods of the RowManager class.  Internally, the implementation of such methods export the plan for sending to the server.

In particular, the following RowManager methods take a plan and get its result rows or an explanation of the query preparation:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/expression/class-use/PlanBuilder.Plan.html#com.marklogic.client.row

Here is an example of getting result rows:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/OpticJava#id_93678

RowManager also provides methods for binding parameters of the plan to literal values before sending the plan to the server:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/expression/class-use/PlanBuilder.Plan.html#com.marklogic.client.expression

Examples of edge cases where an application might want to export a plan include:

- logging
- inserting into a JSON document so an enode script could import a plan without receiving the plan from the client

The exported plan is a JSON document (represented as a String, if the exportAs() method is used).  After exporting the plan, the application could process the JSON document in the same way as any other JSON document.  For instance, the application could use JSONDocumentManager to write the plan as a document in the content database.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks!  I use JAVA (outside MarkLogic) to write the file. 
What I am experimenting really is JSON format:
     I use plan.jsonDocument to convert the plan results in JSON. I get the Jackson root node: JacksonHandle(), 
     but the JAVA console ends up sth like:
{"columns":[{"name":"*****"}],"rows":[{"****":{"type":"object","value":...........
     Not a good sight. 
 
     In the ML query console, the result does come out perfectly as JSON format.

Comment: Maybe the Jackson ObjectWriter can help with the serialization?  For instance, https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()